# FireWire reduction disconnects from pc when cable is connected

Tags: windows-10, firewire

I recently started converting my studio to legion 5. Bought apple thunderbolt3 -> thunderbolt2, thunderbolt2 -> firewire reductions and fw 9pin to 6pin cable.
firewire reduction gets successfully detected, but when fw cable is connected (and there is no difference if second end of cable is connected to something or just in air) windows play disconnecting sound and tb2->fw reduction disappears from *thunderbolt control center* and *fw interface* from *device manager*
At first I thought the cable was damaged (short-circuit which triggers overcurrent protection), but I measured it and all pins are connected properly and none of them are shorted except for pins 5,8,9 (A shield, power+, B shield) which is probably right(?).
What's the problem?

edit: although connection of the shielding to the + is not necessarily wrong(?) it is definitely not compatible with the apple reducer

Comment: One thing about adaptor cables generally, is that "two [or more] in a row" never works properly. You need to get one-to-one converters. Macs can still run old firewire gear happily with a single converter - https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MD464ZM/A/thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter - so long as drivers are still available for the OS you're running.

Comment: I was unsure about it tho. but i read lot of posts and this seems to be quite common and reliable configuration for this task. and for my purposes also way more practicall and less expensive than getting mac @Tetsujin

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question [or comment] to have any better guess. three adaptors is never a good start.